# Real functions $f$ and $g$ are one-one and onto, and are mirror images in the line $y=a$. Is $f(x)+g(x)$ one-one/onto/etc?

Tags: functions

> **Question:**
>
> Let $f:R\to R$ and $g:R\to R$ be two one-one and onto functions such that they are mirror images of each other about the line $y=a$. If $h(x)=f(x)+g(x)$, then $h(x)$ is
>
> (A) one-one
>
> (B) into
>
> (C) onto
>
> (D) many-one
>
> Multiple correct answers are possible.

**My approach:**

Since the question didn't mention anything about the nature of functions, I considered both $f$ and $g$ to be linear functions intersecting at the point $(0,a)$ since they are mirror images to each other with respect to the line $y=a$. I considered the functions to be linear as this was the simplest one according to me which is one-one and onto. Finally, I ended up with $h(x)=2a$ and thus the function $h(x)$ is into(option B) and many-one(option D). *My answers are correct.*

> Is there any other formal approach to the problem, by not considering the functions to be linear or anything like that.

Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x$ be any real number.  If $f(x)=y$, then $g(x)=a+(a-y)=2a-y$, since the function are mirrored by $y=a$.  Therefore $f(x)+g(x)=2a$.  Since $x$ was arbitrary, $h(x)=2a$ for all $x$ and is a constant function.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that "being mirror images" wrt line $y=a$ boils down to: $f(x)-a=a-g(x)$ for every $x$ and consequently $h(x)=f(x)+g(x)=2a$ (hence constant).